# For spring-batch transaction is not getting rolled back after exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-transactions, rollback

I am working on a spring-batch, where after reader and processor, writer is responsible to populate data to DB. Writer is calling Service which internally calls DAO layer. In method insertToDB() if some exception occurs the transaction is not being rolled back. PSB my code.

```
public class MyWriter{

@Autowired
private MyService myService;

@Override
public void write(List<? extends MyBO> list) {
  try{
    for(MyBO bo: list){
      myService.insert(bo);
    }
  }
  catch(Exception e){
    log.error("Cant write to DB")
  }
}


public class MyService{
@Autowired
private TableOneDAO tableOneDao;

@Autowired
private TableTwoDAO tableTwoDAO;

@Autowired
private TableThreeDAO tableThreeDAO;

public void insert(MyBO bo){
  try{
      // do other stuff of processing bo and create entity
      MyEntityTableOne myentity1 = getEntityT1(bo);
      MyEntityTableTwo myentity2 = getEntityT2(bo);
      MyEntityTableThree myentity3 = getEntityT3(bo);
      insertToDB(myEntity1,myEntity2,myEntity3);
  }
  catch(Exception e){
    log.error("Error occured.");
    throw new MyException("Error Blah blah occured");
  }
}

@Transactional(value = "txn1")
public void insertToDB(MyEntityTableOne entity1, MyEntityTableTwo entity2, MyEntityTableThree entity3) {
  try{
    tableOneDao.insert(entity1);
    tableTwoDAO.insert(entity2);
    tableThreeDAO.insert(entity3);
  }
  catch(Exception e){
    log.error("Error occured during insert to DB");
    throw new MyException("Error Blah blah occured during DB insert");
  }
}
```

The code goes to the catch block, but doesn't rollback records. If some error occurs during insert of Table2 then entry for Table1 is not rolled-back. And if occurs during table3 insertion then table1 and table2 records are not rolled-back.
If I move the @Transactional annotation to insert() method it works fine. What is root cause of this issue. What I have to do if I want to have transaction only on insertToDB() method.

Comment: I am trying to make it simple: To support `@Transactional` spring wraps the implementing class into a so called proxy and surrounds the method call / class with the _transactional logic_. Now you are calling the `@Transactional` annotated method within the same class. Therefore the proxy is not invoked and the transactional does not work. When moving to `insert`you are invoking the method from outside of the class which means you invoke the method against the proxy. Thats a limitation of Spring AOP (?) I think. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to make it simple: To support `@Transactional` spring wraps the implementing class into a so called proxy and surrounds the method call / class with the transactional logic.

Now you are calling the `@Transactional` annotated method within the same class. Therefore the **proxy** is not invoked and the transactional does not work. When moving the annotation to your  `insert` method you are invoking the method from outside of the class which means you invoke the method against the proxy.

Thats a limitation of Spring AOP (?) I think.

You can do something like following to achieve what you want:

```
public class MyService{
@Ressource
private MyService self;

...

self.insertToDB(myEntity1,myEntity2,myEntity3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your item writer will be already called in a transaction driven by Spring Batch and that you can configure at the step level by providing the transaction manager and transaction attributes. So there is no need to use `@Transactional` in the downstream service used by the writer.

You need to remove that annotation from `MyService` and it should work as expected.